# Rolling Regression: ValueError: endog is required to have ndim 1 but has ndim 2

Tags: python, regression

I am attempting to run a rolling regression on a dataset. But am getting an error code stating that 'endog is required to have ndim 1 but has ndim 2'.

As far as I understand (new to python) the dimension is 1, given the y.shape of (1763,).

I have tried to make it even more 1-d(even though it already is 1-d) with .ravel() and reshape(), but I am still getting the same error code.

Here is the code used which is causing the error:

```
# Start trialing local linear regression
dataset = df.values

X = dataset[:-1,1:]
y = dataset[:-1, 0].flatten()
y.shape, X.shape
```

Output: ((1763,), (1763, 3))

```
rols = RollingOLS(X, y, window=60)
rres = rols.fit()
params = rres.params
print(params.head())
print(params.tail())
```

Error Code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-7ca687ee0af3> in <module>
     14 import pandas as pd
     15 
---> 16 rols = RollingOLS(X, y, window=60)
     17 rres = rols.fit()
     18 params = rres.params

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/rolling.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, window, min_nobs, missing, expanding)
    445         expanding=False
    446     ):
--> 447         super().__init__(
    448             endog,
    449             exog,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/rolling.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, window, weights, min_nobs, missing, expanding)
    154         self.k_constant = k_const
    155         self.data.const_idx = const_idx
--> 156         self._y = array_like(endog, "endog")
    157         nobs = self._y.shape[0]
    158         self._x = array_like(exog, "endog", ndim=2, shape=(nobs, None))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/statsmodels/tools/validation/validation.py in array_like(obj, name, dtype, ndim, maxdim, shape, order, contiguous, optional)
    145         if arr.ndim != ndim:
    146             msg = "{0} is required to have ndim {1} but has ndim {2}"
--> 147             raise ValueError(msg.format(name, ndim, arr.ndim))
    148     if shape is not None:
    149         for actual, req in zip(arr.shape, shape):

ValueError: endog is required to have ndim 1 but has ndim 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RollingOLS(endog, exog, window=None, *, min_nobs=None, missing='drop', expanding=False)
```

Y is endog and X is exog, you need to switch or name arguments explicitly